# How to ban traffic from a specific zone in Google Cloud Compute instance?

Tags: firewall, gcloud

I have created a google cloud compute instance. Even though the machine has no active website or services running on it yet, i noticed that in 24 hours the dashboard reported 1GB traffic from China. I dont have any customers outside of Central Zone. How do I ban all traffic from a particular zone, say China? Or conversely, how do I only allow HTTP traffic from Central Zone?

Answer (score -2):

Similar question was answered on this thread (https://serverfault.com/questions/22462/relatively-easy-way-to-block-all-traffic-from-a-specific-country) which I believe what you are looking for.

Comment: Not similar at all, because this assumes you have your own server, whereas the question was about google cloud.